# How can I split a list into sublists

Tags: java, list

Unfortuantely, I'm in Java 7 so I can't use any Java 8's facilities.

I have the following enum:

```
public enum Type
{
    MAILING,
    RESEPT,
    CURRENT,
    //...
    USER
}
```

and the class container of that type:

```
public class Container
{
    public Type getType()
    {
        // Impl
    }
}
```

Now I have some `List<Container>`. How can I split it into `List<List<Container>>` such that any `List<Container>` in the `List<List<Container>>` contains only `Container`s with the same `getType()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a slightly different Java 7 approach:

```
List<Container> containers = new ArrayList<>();

containers.add(/* ... */);
containers.add(/* ... */);
containers.add(/* ... */);
containers.add(/* ... */);
containers.add(/* ... */);
containers.add(/* ... */);

Map<Type, List<Container>> split = new HashMap<>();

for (Container container : containers) {
    if (!split.containsKey(container.getType())) {
        split.put(container.getType(), new ArrayList<Container>());
    }
    split.get(container.getType()).add(container);
}

List<List<Container>> listOfLists = new ArrayList<>(split.values());
```

Comment: One note, Map doesn't contain the contains method. You probably meant containsKey() instead.

Comment: Thanks, Updated. I didn't actually test this :-)

Comment: @St.Antario Just a note - if you are using Guava (maybe, judging by your comment on the other answer), you can use a MultiMap, that gets rid of some boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

If you have Java 8, you can use the `Stream`-API's `Collectors.groupingBy(...)`. Then you get a `Map<Type, List<Container>>` returned. Then you can just loop over the values of the map and put it into a list.

Comment: I'm sorry for not specifying that important information. I'm still in Java 7

Comment: Is there some Java <8 way to solve it? Probably with Common or guava.

Answer (score 2):

In case of Java 7, I would recommend looping through the enums `values()`.

```
List<Container> completeList = new ArrayList<>();

List<List<Container>> splitList = new ArrayList<>();

for (Type type : Type.values()) {
    List<Container> containerTypeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Container c : completeList) {
        if (c.getType().equals(type)) {
            containerTypeList.add(c);
        }
    }

    splitList.add(containerTypeList);
}
```